# Estou tendo problemas ao deixar um botão azul no blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

O problema aqui é: o estou utilizando um foreach para percorrer um array enquanto tento verificar se $like->id_post === $post->id && $like->id_user === auth()->user()->id se for é pra mostrar um coração azul se não um coração branco, ele faz isso o problema é que como ele percorre tudo com o foreach ele mostra mais de uma vez assim colocando varios corações ao inves de um, se alguem puder me ajudar fico grato

```php
                      <div class="react">
                        <a class="like" onclick="handleLike({{ auth()->user()->id }}, {{ $post->id }} )">
                          @foreach ($likes as $like)
                            
                            @if($like->id_post === $post->id && $like->id_user === auth()->user()->id)
                              <i id="heart{{ $post->id }}" class="fas fa-heart"></i> <span id="like{{ $post->id }}">{{ $post->num_likes }}</span> likes
                            @else
                              <i id="heart{{ $post->id }}" class="far fa-heart"></i> <span id="like{{ $post->id }}">{{ $post->num_likes }}</span> likes
                            @endif
                          @endforeach
                        </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach ($likes as $like)
   @if($like->id_post === $post->id && $like->id_user === auth()->user()->id)
     //Se o post tiver like

   @break // Break no foreach

   @elseif($loop->last) //Se for a última interação ( se chegar até aqui, não houve 'break', logo não houve um post com like
      //Se o post tiver não tiver like
   @endif
@endforeach
```